# Why won't my nav's bottom border stay solid for my current List item

Tags: html, css

Here's the js fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/h0hrm8m2/ `here's the JSFiddle` outside JS fiddle on the hover it changes the color of the bottom to gold.

Comment: Add you code please or make a link on jsfiddle

Comment: @Maddy need to do both =P or at least 1st

Comment: @Maddy yeah sorry, forgot to add that lol.

Comment: Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h0hrm8m2/1/

Comment: @dfsq Thanks mate, do you know of a way to have the current LI item's bottom border color persistent?

Comment: Your `nav ul li a:hover` is not closed properly.

Comment: @Tims thank's that's fixed, now my original question was how can I have the current list item marked by the id #current keep the border color outside of the hover? if that makes sense.

Comment: Does your page reload when you click links?

Comment: @dfsq in my local page, it does not.

Comment: Then you would need javascript for this (well it's possible to make it without javascript too, but better with).

Comment: @dfsq I don't want it in Javascript haha, I just wrote it up in JSfiddle because it was easiest.

Comment: Are you sure? You **can** do it in pure CSS, no problem. But javascript is more natural here.

Comment: @dfsq I have no idea how I could do it in Javascript or CSS, care to enlighten me?

Comment: Like this for example: http://jsfiddle.net/h0hrm8m2/3/

Answer (score 0):

Close the tag:-

```
nav ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: solid 0.15em rgb(255,215,0)
}
```

```css
nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
nav ul li a {
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin: 1%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 2%;
    padding-top: 3%;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: solid 0.15em rgb(255, 215, 0);
}
nav ul li a #current {
    border-bottom:solid 1px rgb(250, 215, 0);
}
```

```html
<nav>
            <ul>
            
                <li id="current"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LOCATION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">RESERVATIONS</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nav ul li a:hover
{
border-bottom: solid 1px gold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got your selectors slightly wrong.  You should also not be using an id for `current`.  Use a class instead:

```
<nav>
    <ul>        
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LOCATION</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">RESERVATIONS</a></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

and

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin: 1%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 2%;
    padding-top: 3%;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: solid 0.15em rgb(255,215,0)
}

nav ul li.active a {
    border-bottom:solid 1px rgb(250,215,0);
}
```

This last class (`nav ul li.active a`) is the one that will make your active item keep its coloured border.

Comment: Did you note the change from an id to a class in the html?